# ASP.NET MVC Only use route to access controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller action that I only want users to be able to access by using a friendly route.

So instead of going to "/controller/action"
They should only be able to go to "/controller-action"

This is the route I have setup for this.

```
routes.MapRoute("ControllerAction",
                            "controller-action",
                            new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" });
```

Is there any way to keep this route to this controller/action while redirecting requests from /controller/action to /controller-action ?

The reason this is being asked for is to keep our paths "less deep" for seo reasons.

Comment: I would hardly call `controller-action` any more friendly than `controller/action`, but regardless...what are you asking? Keep both routes as valid but redirect if `controller/action` is seen?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for... If you don't want "/controller/action" route than just don't define it.

Comment: I would like for /controller-action to be the only one that works, and /controller/action would redirect to /controller-action.

Comment: configure an http redirect in iis?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried `routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}-{action}",defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});`